# Evaluate $\iiint_V(x+2y+3z)\,dx\,dy\,dz$ without changing the variables

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I'm having some difficulty with evaluating  $\iiint_V(x+2y+3z)\,dx\,dy\,dz$ where

$V:$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
0 \le x+y+z \le 1 \\ 
0 \le z-x \le 2 \\ 
0 \le x+y \le1
\end{array}
\right. 
$

without having to change variables. Yesterday, when I was introduced to this triple integral, my lecturer mentioned  that it is doable, but requires considering some cases. What would those cases be? I'd be grateful for an outline of the solution.

By the way, the result I obtained after changing my variables is $4$. Each time I try to solve the problem the other way I get some other number..

Thank you for taking your time to help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Computing this integral with about six triple integrals of the form
$$\int_a^b\int_{c(x)}^{d(x)}\int_{u(x,y)}^{v(x,y}(x+2y+3z) dz\>dy\>dx$$
is hopeless. Instead we argue as follows:

The body $V$ is a parallelohedron bounded by three planes $\pi_i$ through te origin $O$ and three parallel planes $\pi'_i$. Intersecting two $\pi_i$s and the third $\pi'_i$ gives the other endpoint of an edge through $O$. In this way, solving
$$x+y+z=0,\quad z-x=0,\quad x+y=1$$
we obtain $a=(-1,2,-1)$. Similarly we obtain $b=(-2,2,0)$ and $c=(1,-1,1)$. It follows that
$${\rm vol}(V)=\bigl|(a\times b)\cdot c\bigr|=2\ .$$
On the other hand  $V$ has center
$$m={1\over2}(a+b+c)=\left(-1,{3\over2},0\right)\ .$$
Happily the integrand $f(x,y,z):=x+2y+3z$ is a linear function. This immediately implies by symmetry that
$$\int_Vf(x,y,z)\>{\rm d}(x,y,z)=f(m)\>{\rm vol}(V)=2\cdot2=4\ .$$